# Flutter go_router Bad state: No element when popping after refreshListenable cubit emits state

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, bloc

There is go_router with 3 cubit streams merged into one.

```
GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
refreshListenable: GoRouterRefreshStream(StreamGroup.merge(
  [
    GetIt.I<AuthBloc>().stream,
    GetIt.I<SignUpFormCubit>().stream,
    GetIt.I<SignInFormCubit>().stream,
  ],
)),
// redirect to the login page if the user is not logged in
redirect: (state) {
  // if the user is not logged in, they need to login
  final loggedIn = GetIt.I<FirebaseAuth>().currentUser != null;
  final loggingIn = (state.subloc == Routes.auth ||
      state.subloc == Routes.signUp ||
      state.subloc == Routes.signIn);
  // if (!loggedIn) return loggingIn ? null : Routes.auth;
  // todo delete
  if (!loggedIn) return loggingIn ? null : Routes.auth;

  // if the user is logged in but still on the login page, send them to
  // the home page
  if (loggingIn) return Routes.home;

  // no need to redirect at all
  return null;
},
routes: <GoRoute>[
  GoRoute(
    path: Routes.home,
    builder: (context, GoRouterState state) => InitialPage(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: Routes.auth,
    builder: (context, GoRouterState state) => AuthPage(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: Routes.signUp,
    builder: (context, GoRouterState state) => SignUpPage(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: Routes.signIn,
    builder: (context, GoRouterState state) => SignInPage(),
  ),
],
);
```

from **auth** route is a possibility to move to **sign in** route:

```
context.push(Routes.signIn);
```

and reversed go back from **sign in** to **auth** route

it works as expected until the cubit emits some state.

**SignInFormCubit**(take a look to refreshListenable) emits a state every time there is some validation error e.g. mail is not correct.

The problem is that when any state is emitted back button stops working as expected:
[image]

```
The following StateError was thrown building Builder(dirty):
Bad state: No element

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Spacing Spacing:file:///Users/sergiyvergun/IdeaProjects/Fleengo/lib/app/core.dart:160:16
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.last (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:365:5)
#1      GoRouterDelegate.location (package:go_router/src/go_router_delegate.dart:192:32)
#2      GoRouterDelegate._builder (package:go_router/src/go_router_delegate.dart:647:33)
#3      GoRouterDelegate.build (package:go_router/src/go_router_delegate.dart:215:41)
#4      Builder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/basic.dart:7398:48)
#5      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4827:28)
#6      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#7      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Any luck? Similar issue here

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem of Bad state: No element. My problem was using the "redirect" parameter on the base or main route. When I removed the "redirect" param from the base route it solved.

But this thing was mentioned nowhere